# How do I say ‘honours degree’ / ‘honours thesis’ in German?

Tags: vocabulary, technical-terminology, education

I completed my **honours degree** last year at university. To my knowledge, the German education system does not have a comparable degree (an additional year of **research** culminating in a **thesis** which may be undertaken after completion of the Bachelor degree given if your **marks** were good enough).

What would I call this in German? *Ehren*? Would someone know what I meant if I said *Honours*?

Also what is the correct term for the thesis? *Dissertation* is for PhDs and *Aufsatz* is way to general I think. I know the term *Bachelor-Arbeit*, could I say *Honours-Arbeit*?

I am writing to a publishing company in Germany and I want to make sure I use the right terms.

Comment: I don't know of a proper German equivalent. I commonly see people advertising their degree around me as BSc (Hons), so would expect any German company with a *bit* of international standing should have an idea about the English original.

Comment: What you write in your first paragraph is not what "honours degree" means in the UK. Which country are you talking about?

Comment: If a normal Bachelor’s degree doesn’t include a thesis in your country, your Honors degree may compare well to a German/European Bachelor degree which is awarded after a three to four-year programme with a median workload of 4500–7200 hours depending on country and college/university.

Comment: Don't try to use a German word for something that doesn't exist in this way in Germany. Use the English word and explain, just like you did above. There's "Diplomarbeit" and "Doktorarbeit", so I'd use some generic compound with "-arbeit", e.g. "Abschlussarbeit". Again, explain what it is for.

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bachelor I am not sure about which "Honour" is meant in this question, but here are some explained in German.

Comment: See also https://www.internationales-management-studieren.de/infos/joint-programme/auslaendische-abschluesse/. As dirkt mentioned in his comment, it does not exist in Germany, hence there is no German expression.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding academic degrees from different, non-aligned education systems, an explanation or description is usually better than a translation. *[Honours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honours_degree)* (or *honors*) in particular should never be translated as *Ehren-* or even *ehrenhalber* (e.h., eh.), because that’s an [honor**ary** degree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honorary_degree) (Latin: *honoris causa, h.c., hc.*) which is always awarded without a thesis, sometimes even without requiring formal studies.

The spelling with *ou* and the [Wikpedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honours_degree) suggest that the OP acquired his degree in the UK or a Commonwealth country, but not the US. Inside the EU (so including England, Wales, Scotland, Ireland, Malta), the [Bologna Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bologna_Process) should require the issuing university to supply the diploma with an explanation and the degree should be comparable by workload, acquired skills and difficulty to other European degrees.

Bachelor programmes at a German *Universität* (or *Fachhochschule*) usually include a mandatory thesis concluding a three-year study programme (6 semesters, 180 [ECTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Credit_Transfer_and_Accumulation_System) credit points of median 30 hours workload each), rarely longer (at most 8 semesters, 210 or 240 CPs). A British Honours degree after a Bachelor programme seems therefore comparable.

If it’s unusual – an actual honour – to write a thesis at a certain university, and this may be well known to the prospective employer, an applicant should stress that their qualification is at least comparable to that of a German student. Anyone working in human resources who knows about such differences between academic systems should be familiar with the English term, so a translation isn’t needed – after all, we’re using anglicisms *Bachelor* and *Master* now (instead of direct Romanisms like *Magister, Diplom, Ingenieur*). Some may even be rejecting applicants with just an Ordinary / Pass / General degree, because they’re considered too inferior. German HR departments are often quite keen on titles, diplomas and certificates; Austrian ones even more so – at least so I’ve heard.

An Australian Honours degree as part of a four-year programme may be harder (And necessary) to explain in Europe. I remember briefly meeting an Aussie complaining about this. One should stress the selective, competitive and research aspects of the degree. If one still wanted a translation, I’ll offer these:

- *Bachelorabschluss mit Auszeichnung* – stresses the grades (possibly [A and B class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECTS_grading_scale))
- *Abschluss mit Forschungssemester* – stresses the increased length and research aspect
- *Bachelor mit Forschungsschwerpunkt* – emphasises the research aspect

The title of the thesis (*Abschlussarbeit* or *Bachelorarbeit*) can – often should – be part of a job application and by its mere existence indicates that one was successfully written.

Comment: Crissov, did you just answer this with your opinion and not really knowing any answer at all? You also gave a lot of comparisons which was not asked for at all. For information, UK Honours degrees are usually 4 years, not three. A basic batchelors degree is three years without honours. so please get your facts straight.

Comment: @iain9876 Sorry to reply to an old comment, but that's not true. A typical first degree in the UK is three or four years, usually leading to a bachelor's degree with honours ('with honours' so universal that it is often not mentioned; not getting honours is essentially equivalent to failing in most places). Some first degrees have 'master' in the name, particularly Scottish first degrees (MA, equivalent to English BA) and integrated masters (MMath, MPhys etc., roughly equivalent to bachelors + one-year masters).

Comment: See these pages, for instance, and click on a few courses to see their length: https://www.plymouth.ac.uk/courses/undergraduate https://www.liverpool.ac.uk/study/undergraduate/courses/ https://www.lboro.ac.uk/study/undergraduate/courses/a-z/ – plenty of university websites don't mention 'Hons' because it's so universal in the UK as to be irrelevant.