# How to add my honour student and high honour certificate to my cv in german?

Tags: meaning, translation, english-to-german, german-to-english, austrian

I have 3 Honour student certificates and 1 High Honour certificate. I am currently writing my cv for my university application in Austria. How should I translate these certificates? Is there any certificates equal to mine in Austria?

Comment: Could you explain what it is? In what country were they issued?

Comment: Wikipedia has an [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honors_student), but apparently it's not well-known outside the US. In addition, the US has a [National Honor Society](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Honor_Society). In the US people also talk about a student's Grade Point Average, the average of grades converted to a numerical scale. I have no idea if that's something people do in German speaking areas.

Comment: Closely related question: [*How do I say ‘honours degree’ / ‘honours thesis’ in German?*](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/28873/how-do-i-say-honours-degree-honours-thesis-in-german/28994#28994)

Comment: If you apply for a job at a **university**, they will probably have heard about this type of certificate before. But do not translate it. Not even "Master" or "Bachelor" are translated.

Answer (score 1):

As others explained, it is not well known in Germany, and you will always need to explain it. I would not translate the degree itself as there is no equivalent, I also call it 'honours degree' in German.

My usual explanation is that it is a degree between the Bachelor and the Master (at least that's true for the honours degree I received in new Zealand where it is also known: but I am not aware of the difference of a 'normal' and a 'high ' honours degree)